# How to Add Libraries When Working with Egit on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven, egit

I'm using E-git plugin for Eclipse IDE. I wanna use some libraries in my project. I normally add them as maven dependency when building, but i'm annoyed at the error messages that eclipse gives and being not able to use code hinting. Is there a way to dynamically link the library from artifact repo or what's the right way of adding it to my project (i dont want to upload it to github).

**In short:**

I want to use library features in Eclipse (code completion, to browse inside the class, etc) without adding it to my GitHub.

Comment: Which error message you didn't mentioned ?

Comment: Ones given because I couldn't add library to my project. E.g. Class cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: Are this libraries not available in Maven?

Comment: They are available in Maven. I can build the project. But I can't use Eclipse for code completion and it gives stupid errors thinking it's not there.

Comment: There are some contradiction in your statements .Do you want these library in E-git or eclipse?

Comment: I just want to use library features in Eclipse (code completion, to browse inside the class, etc) without adding it to my GitHub.